# How to add slider in datalist controll

Tags: asp.net

I want to add slider in datalist controll.

```
<ItemTemplate>
<img alt=""  src='Image/<%#Eval("Image") %>' /><br />
</a>
<h4><asp:Label ID="lb" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12pt" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Label><br />
Product Code: <span><%# Eval("product_code") %></span></h4>
<span ><del>&#2352;</del><%# Eval("Our_price") %>INR</span><br />
<a href='Shopping_Cart.aspx?cart_id=<%# Eval("id") %>'>Add to Cart</a>
```

Now I  want to add slider so that all products could slide with images.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question was not Clear what i understood is that u want to scroll your item list. Give your Datalist a fixed size(height and width) and overflow:scrolling in css

```
style='height:400;width:500; overflow:scrolling'
```

Comment: I want Images slide automatically, dont want scrolling.

Comment: See this slider http://labs.juliendecaudin.com/barousel/#ba_demos. But u have to implement it

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you can do it dynamically.You can use image slider into datalist as below:

```
<div id="box">

<div id="slider">
    <div class="slider">

        <ul>
            <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="7" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src='<%#Eval("Path") %>' alt="" width="272" height="170" runat="server"/></a></li>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:DataList> 

        </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="sliderButon">
    <a href="#" class="onceki">Previous</a>
    <a href="#" class="sonraki">Next</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```